# What is wrong with my .bashrc PS1 line?

Tags: bash

I think the screenshot should show what's going on. I open a shell, and dir colors don't work. I run bash again, and dir colors work. What's going on?

[image]

Comment: Better show us the outputs of the `alias ls`, `echo $LS_OPTIONS` and `echo $LS_COLORS` commands both when colors work and when not.

Comment: I moved my PS1 line below the "source global definitions" section. I guess the color alias was in the global bashrc. Learn something every day!

Comment: @LVLAaron The configuration process in general (i.e. this applies to many programs) reads global settings before user specific settings so that users can override defaults with their own preferences.  You would only put your own settings before sourcing a global file if you intentionally want any global settings to override your own.  If that is not your goal, move everything after the "source global definitions" part.

Answer (score 3):

`.bashrc` is only read for non-login shells. So when you first log in, its not read. When you run `bash` again, its not a login shell, so it reads it and your settings take effect.

The simplest solution to this is to create `~/.bash_profile` with the following contents:

```
source .bashrc
```

This will make a login shell read the config used for non-login shells.

Answer (score 0):

I think you gave some command which unaliased everything and after that when you gave bash command again, the .bashrc was read again and all the variables were aliased again and it executed that alias commands which are mentioned in the .bashrc file of root user and I can see one command is there which is aliasing **ls** command also, so that's why the color came again.